# How to hide directories for each user in NON- AD windows environment?

Tags: windows

It is possible to hide any other folders on the terminal server user's C drive so that the only folders they see are the shared folders they have access to? It isn't a huge issue but I think it would be cleaner and easier if they users only saw the folders they could access. Something like Hidden share

Comment: Not really what you are looking for but you can add a dollar sign ($) to the end of the folder name and it will hide it

Comment: @Kyle: No, Adding a dollar sign to the end of a folder name changes the folder name to foldername$, it does not hide the folder. Adding a dollar sign to the end of a share name hides the share. Folder names and share names are two different things. If you meant to say "Share the folder with a share name with a dollar sign" then you're correct.

Comment: @Kyle: Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your use case I don't know if this is applicable to you but you could create the folder tree within each user's personal profile. Other users then shouldn't see them because they won't have access to that profile.

Answer (score 1):

There's ABE (access based enumeration) but I'm not sure it's appropriate in this scenario.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710(WS.10).aspx

Comment: ABE sorry to say does not help when accessesing with terminal server access, Dan